# PHP Mail form, receiving MISSING_MAILBOX@syntax_error at the given mail

Tags: php, css, email

I've kinda changed a mail form into a form for request by mail, working on the same principle tho, currently i managed to reach to this point ->

```
 <?php
ob_start();
$ploskost = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ploskost']); 
$from = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
$lengthmm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['lengthmm']); 
$widthmm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['widthmm']); 
$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']); 
$gsm = htmlspecialchars($_POST['gsm']); 
$message = htmlspecialchars($_POST['message']); 
$to         = 'office@estersps.net';

$headers  = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: {$name} <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: <{$from}>\r\n";
$headers .= "Subject: {$ploskost} <{$lengthmm}> \r\n <{$widthmm}> \r\n} ";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\r\n";

mail($to, $name, $gsm, $headers, $message);
die;
```

but on the given mail I am receiving a mail with no topic, from "MISSING_MAILBOX@syntax_error" with no content. When i've definetely given the info that it needs to send.

Here is the HTML if you need it.

```html
<form id="main-contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="http://estersps.net/razkroy.php">
                <div class="row  wow fadeInUp" data-wow-duration="1000ms" data-wow-delay="300ms">
                  <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="ploskost" class="form-control" placeholder="Вид плоскост" required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-10">

                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" name="lengthmm" class="form-control" placeholder="Дължина на детайла по фладера за дървесните видове в mm." required>
                    </div>
                  </div>
               
      <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="widthmm" class="form-control" placeholder="Ширина на детайла /в мм./" required>
                </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Вашето име" required>
                </div>
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="gsm" class="form-control" placeholder="Телефон за връзка с вас" required>
                </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="Допълнителна информация" ></textarea>
                </div>          
</div>    
 <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Вашият емайл адрес" required>
                </div>
    </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button class="btn-submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Изпрати</button>
                </div>
    </div>
              </form>
```